# Unable to call method in Different class . (Java/GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I am writing a code in GWT client Side.
I am getting a error in calling a method in other class.  Please see the below code.

```
        public class QTypeBox extends Composite {
            public FlexTable textTypeFlexTable;

        public QTypeBox() {

            textTypeFlexTable = new FlexTable();
            initWidget(textTypeFlexTable);
            textTypeFlexTable.setSize("520px", "100px");                                
            //addImageTypeBox(0);
            //addTextBox(2);
            //addMatchPairBow(9);

        }

        public int getPosition(){
            int i =textTypeFlexTable.getRowCount();
            return i;
        }       
        public void addImageTypeBox(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Image image = new Image((String) null);
            textTypeFlexTable.setWidget(0, 0, image);
        }
         public void addMP(int i){
            Label lblColumnA = new Label("Column A");
            textTypeFlexTable.setWidget(i, 0, lblColumnA);

            Label lblColumnB = new Label("Column B");
            textTypeFlexTable.setWidget(i, 4, lblColumnB);
         }
    }

////

    public class Test extends Composite {

            private FlexTable flexTable_2;

            public Test() {
            initWidget(flexTable_2);


            QTypeBox qTypeBox = new QTypeBox();
            qTypeBox.addMP(4);//**<<<<--------------**


           }
```

In class Test , where i have marked like **<<<<----------** is showing me error.

```
The method addMP(int) is undefined for the type QTypeBox
```

I checked the Hint, It asked me to create a method addMP(int) in `QtypeBox`. If i do this , again it ask me to change the name of Existing method `addMP`

Can anyone guide where i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Your code shows qBox but you are instantiating qTypeBox.  Is qBox an instance from somewhere else?

Comment: Is the `QTypeBox` you instanciate in `Test` the same type (within the same package) like the `QTypeBox` from your example?

Comment: Yes they both are in same package..

Comment: You could try cleaning your project (in Eclipse it's Project -> Clean). Are you using Maven/Ant/Gradle? Does your project compile that way?

Comment: Did you try to clear gwt compile cache?

Comment: Cleaning Helped. When i add more methods in `QTypeBox ` and tried to call form `Test `. It gave me same problem. Deleting and Recreating QType Box resolved this weird problem, Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is clean. The error is due to eclipse not recognizing the class and its methods.

Any one of this steps will resolve your problem

- Clean Build your project
- Refresh your project
- Delete the classes manually and clean build your project
- Close and open your eclipse
  If none of the above works then the below one will surely resolve your problem
- Delete and recreate your classes again